# How can I create headings like these in Microsoft word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I was writing a document.

It should have headings like these

[image]

I have searched it on YouTube, but I could not find any way to accomplish this. How are they made?

Comment: the image is revealing too much info .. you should mask sensitive data

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are calling a ribbon, is really a background shading on a paragraph. What you are asking for, is very easy to do.

1. Select the text, including the paragraph mark.
2. From the `Paragraph group` on the `Home tab` of Word's ribbon, use the `Borders menu` button to select the `Format Boarders and Shading` control.

[image]

3. From the `Shading` tab on the `Borders and Shading` dialog, select the
   `Fill Color` to use and make sure the `Apply to:` menu is set to "Paragraph."

[image]

Comment: Easier: Place the caret anywhere in the paragraph you want to give a background colour to, and then simply click the arrow next to the bucket icon immediately to the left of the icon in Rich's answer. [But of course, if you have more than a single paragraph like this in your document, you really should create a style for it. That style likely contains other properties in addition to the background colour: margins, style of the following paragraph, etc.]

Comment: You can also use Patterns instead of a Fill. If you pick clear and 10-15%, you get a nice gray bar. I've seen Fills render with a moire pattern but never a Pattern.